# Where DATE and TODATE causes and unknown command error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble with a date filter expression. I am using SQL Developer and am getting wrong results and an unknown command error at the bottom of the results.

```
select cmp.company_name, sum (inv.total_price), max (inv.invoice_date)
 from   companies cmp join invc_header inv on cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key
 group by cmp.company_name;
 where inv.invoice_date = '2017-01-27'
```

I also used where inv.invoice_date = '2017-01-27'

The error is "unknown command"

Jeff

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the "unknown command error" because you have a semi-colon `;` in the middle of your query. Semi-colons are used to terminate a statement so the SQL parser thinks that you have a second statement `where inv.invoice_date = '2017-01-27'` after the first one and it does not know how to parse it.

To fix it, the `WHERE` clause needs to come before the `GROUP BY`.

Other than that, `'2017-01-27'` is not a date; it is a string literal that just happens to look like a date. `DATE '2017-01-27'` is a date literal or you can use the function `TO_DATE( '2017-01-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )` to explicitly convert the string to a date.

```sql
SELECT cmp.company_name,
       SUM(inv.total_price),
       MAX (inv.invoice_date)
FROM   companies cmp
       JOIN invc_header inv
       ON cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key
WHERE inv.invoice_date = DATE '2017-01-27'
GROUP BY cmp.company_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the colon. I had it a bit mixed up.  I did a test on our data base and it shows RR-MM-DD.  The table shows it as a DATE field.

Comment: @Jeff A `DATE` data type is stored as 7-bytes (which is always century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second); it has no format. The user interface you are using will format the binary data in a way that will make more sense to you, the user, and that format may be `RR-MM-DD` but that format can be changed by the user and is unrelated to the data stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off. You need to have your `WHERE` clause before your `GROUP BY`. Also you can add the keyword `DATE` if you are specify a date as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format to have the value treated as a date type instead of a string.

```sql
  SELECT cmp.company_name, SUM (inv.total_price), MAX (inv.invoice_date)
    FROM companies cmp JOIN invc_header inv ON cmp.cmp_auto_key = inv.cmp_auto_key
   WHERE inv.invoice_date = date '2017-01-27'
GROUP BY cmp.company_name;
```